# Electric Dipole Approximation, multiple electron transition and spectroscopic notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, radiation

My question is : $$ 1s^22s2p\ ~^1P_1\ -> 1s^22p3p\ ~^1P_1  $$would such a transition be possible?
I am not very good with spectroscopic notation, but I think this means several electrons would undergo transition, as $2s -> 2p$ and $2p->3p$. I am thinking that "no" is the answer for an electric dipole approximation as I feel that transitions of multiple electrons are not allowed. So is it possible, and if it is not, have I given the right reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised, that this is not a many electron transition. 2s goes to 3p. No other rules are violated, so this transition is fine.